# Create URL in Razor View for Attribute Route containing parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, attributerouting

I have the controller below with a route specified which contains a parameters matching the overload on the action.

```
public class OrganisationsController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("organisations/{id}/employees")]
    public ActionResult Employees(int id)
    {
        //  Some code here
    }
}
```

I'm trying to create the URL in a Razor View using `@Html.ActionLink` to match the route specified on the controller, for example `localhost:55416/Organisations/2/Employees`, but I've not been able to get it working.

The closest I've been able to get is `localhost:55416/Organisations/Employees/2` which doesn't work as the route is wrong, or `localhost:55416/Organisations/Employees?id=2` which actually works as the Employees action on the Organisations controller is hit, but then it's just a query string then which negates the purpose of adding the `[Route("organisations/{id}/employees")]` route in the first place.

All the examples and posts I've been able to find on the interwebs deal with the parameter being at the end, for example `[Route("organisations/employees/{id}")]`, and not in between the controller and the action.

I haven't bothered by trying to add custom route to the `RouteConfig` as in my mind the URL is the starting point which needs to be correct first according to the Route specified on the controller, or am I wrong here?

Is there a way for me to generate the URL the way I want it to using `ActionLink`, or is there another way I need to go about doing this?

Comment: Have you tried `@Html.ActionLink("myLink", "Employees","Organisations",new { id = 2 },null)`

Comment: @sam, hi, yes I have, when using `@Html.ActionLink("Employees", "Employees", "Organisations", new { id = item.Id }, null)` I get the localhost:55416/Organisations/Employees/2 URL.

Comment: Could you submit your `RouteConfig` class then?

Comment: @sam you legend, I have one solution with two separate projects, one for the MVC WebApp and one for the WebAPI, I see now I only added `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` to the RouteConfig.cs for the WebAPI and not for the MVC WebApp also, which is where I was trying to create the URL.  I added it and the above ActionLink is now generating correct localhost:55416/organisations/2/employees url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit should go to Sam, the ActionLink he provided was correct, the reason it didn't work when I tried it was because I did not add the `routes.MapMvcAttributesRoutes();` line to the RouteConfig.cs of the project in which I was trying to create the URL, after adding it the expected `localhost:55416/Organisations/2/Employees` url gets generated by the `@Html.ActionLink("Employees", "Employees", "Organisations", new { id = item.Id }, null)` action link.

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```